# wpf app - why is the window size larger than I set it to?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, height

Any ideas re why the WPF application I've starting building has a larger width and height than what I set in VS2010?

That is, in VS2010 I set the height of the window to be AUTO (so it should be just high enough to contain the controls) and this seems to work visually within VS2010.  But when I then run the application the window height of the app is much larger than this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting the SizeToContent property of the Window to WidthAndHeight ?